# What is the best way to tidy outdoor items around block paving?

Tags: outdoor, brick, driveway, coaxial-cable

There are 3 aspects (circled in red) that[image] I would like to tidy around some bricks and block paving. 2 cables coming out of brickwork into the block paving on both ends, and cuts around a drain. Are there products that would do this and can be cut to size?

I have seen things this cover but its not quite wide enough.

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Cable-Cover-Plate-Brick-Buster-Blast-Exterior-Walls-TV-Coax-Sky-Satellite-CCTV-/202193245877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty common to just use a matching silicone sealant around the cables, brown or black in this case. If using plastic covers, you'd probably have to buy two and cut them down to meet in the middle.

The drain pipe needs some mortar with a drop of red cement colouring (a powder usually) mixed into it. Wrap a piece of polythene around the pipe first and carefully slide/twist it out after 2 or 3 hours (before it sets really hard).

Alternatively, fill around the pipe with a small decorative gravel, although sweeping may pull this out over time.

Comment: Small decorative gravel similar to brick colour sounds like a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try filling it in with some gravel and then a thin skim coat of matching sanded grout or mortar. Also match the brick paint and paint the wires and drain pipe.